# Solve the following nxn determinant by reducing it to a upper/lower triangular determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm to use transformations and reduce this determinant to an upper or lower triangular one but I don't even know where to begin.
$$det \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 & 2 & ... & 2 \\
5 & 4 & 5 & ... & 5 \\
5 & 5 & 6 & ... & 5 \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
5 & 5 & 5 & ... & 2n
 \end{pmatrix}$$
Any ideas? What's the first step?

Comment: Use the same row reduction techniques you would use to solve a system of linear equations. if you can get it into upper triangular form then the determinant is just the product of the diagonal entries.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the second column from the first one to generate lots of $0$  in the first column.

Try to find columns or rows which by subtraction generate $0$ in columns or rows.

Be careful to follow the rules of effect of the elementary row or column operatons on determinants.

Comment: Okay, by doing that you get $$det \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 2 & ... & 2 \\
1 & 4 & 5 & ... & 5 \\
0 & 5 & 6 & ... & 5 \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
0 & 5 & 5 & ... & 2n
 \end{pmatrix}$$ Where do I go from there?

Comment: Now swap the first two rows to have a $1$ at $a_{11}$. Your determinant multiplies by a $-1$.

Comment: So I got: $$det -\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 5 & ... & 5 \\
0 & 2 & 2 & ... & 2 \\
0 & 5 & 6 & ... & 5 \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
0 & 5 & 5 & ... & 2n
 \end{pmatrix}$$. Then I can multiply row 2 by 1/2 to get:

Comment: $$det -\begin{pmatrix}1 & 4 & 5 & ... & 5 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\
0 & 5 & 6 & ... & 5 \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
0 & 5 & 5 & ... & 2n
 \end{pmatrix}$$ From there, I can add row 2 multiplied by -5 to row 3 and row n and get: $$det -\begin{pmatrix}1 & 4 & 5 & ... & 5 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & ... & 0 \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 2n-5
 \end{pmatrix}$$ So the solution is $2n-5$. Does that seem right?
EDIT: Multiplied by $1/2$

Comment: Wow! You did it.

Comment: @crylikeacanary 2n-5 is the determinant of the last matrix. Did you keep track of your row swaps?

Comment: There was one row swap which means I multiply by $-1$ and one multiplying of a row by $1/2$ which I multiply the determinant by that so the end result should be $-1/2 * (2n-5)$, right?